# Can I store my custom comment_type into wp_comments table?

Tags: comments, database

I'm developing a system where a post can have multiple replies/feedbacks. As of now I's storing each of the comments as a serialized `postmeta`. But just today I figured out that I can use the existing `comments` table for the same purpose, and where there is a `commentmeta` table I can store additional data there too.

So I came up using the [`wp_insert_comment()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment), and I hope more robust one is [`wp_new_comment()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_comment), where I introduced with the [**`comment_type`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_type) parameter. I found that it stores:

- `null` for default comment type 'comments',
- `pingback` for 'pingbacks', and
- `trackbacks` for 'trackbacks'

As it seems similar to `wp_posts`' `post_type` column, but is that actually is like that? Is it safe storing my custom `comment_type` there to keep trace of certain types of comments/feedbacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comment type is similar to post type, because it allow to query only a specific type of comments, just like post type allow to query one or more post types.

And just like core post types (page, post) there are core comment type as well: `'comment'`, `'pingback'`, `'trackback'`.

A difference between the two is that, by default, `WP_Query` do not fetch post types that are not explicilty required, but only the `'post'` post type.

On the countrary, [`WP_Comment_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/), by default, fecth all comment types.

A lot of themes use [`wp_list_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_comments/) to show comments.

That function has a `'type'` argument that allow to set the comment type to show.

If you look at, for example, default themes, that function [is used without the type argument](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/comments.php#L37). It means that, even if you use a custom comment type, that *special* comments will be shown among "regular" comments by most of the themes.

To overcome this issue you can use the [`'pre_get_comments'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_comments/) hook to prevent your custom comment types to be fetched along "standard" comment types:

```
/* Assuming 'my_custom_comment_type' is the name of custom comment type */

add_action( 'pre_get_comments', function(\WP_Comment_Query $query) {
   /* only allow 'my_custom_comment_type' when is required explicitly */
   if ( $query->query_vars['type'] !== 'my_custom_comment_type' ) {
      $query->query_vars['type__not_in'] = array_merge(
          (array) $query->query_vars['type__not_in'],
          array('my_custom_comment_type')
      );
   }
});
```

Using code above, you can safely use `'my_custom_comment_type'` to store comments that will be not mixed up with standard comments.

After that, when you need to fetch your custom comments, you need to explicitly pass the comment type slug, and everything should work fine.

However, note that functions normally used to retrieve comments, like [`wp_list_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_comments/) or [`get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) automatically exclude comments that are not approved (or spam).

In fact, depending on your settings, if you use [`wp_new_comment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_comment/) to store your custom comments, it is possible that they are stored as not approved and you will not able to fecth those comments even if explicitly using proper `'type'` argument.

To avoid this, there are 3 possibilities:

- always use the `'status'` argument of `WP_Comment_Query` (or `get_comments()`) set to `"all"` when fetching custom comments type: this way all comments will be fecthed no matter if approved or not
- use the more low-level `wp_insert_comment()` to save the comment, and set `'approved'` argument to `1`
- use the filter ['pre_comment_approved'](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_comment_approved/) to always store as approved comments having your custom comment type:

  ```
  add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', function( $approved, $data ) {
      return isset($data['comment_type']) && $data['comment_type'] === 'my_custom_comment_type'
         ? 1
         : $approved;
  }, 20, 2);
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another more in-depth answer from you - thanks a lot. [1] Anyway, I found [`'comment_approved'`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.1/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L2294) parameter is working for `wp_new_comment()` too - so currently with your suggestion, I can insert new comment successfully. [2] I'm not actually concerned about the `pre_get_comments` action hooking, because If my custom comment has `comment_post_ID` `111` it won't show up at the post `112` - isn't that? Though a fail safe is always better. I'm now stuck with another issue, probably I'll ask another.

Comment: I updated the [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_comment#Examples) with the tested example. Please have a look if I'm right, or not. :)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam the line you linked proof that **1.** `wp_new_comment()` **ovverride** `'comment_approved'` field with the result of `wp_allow_comment()`, no matter what you passed. **2.** If you insert the comment for a post it will be visible on that post, but if that post has other kind of comments they will be mixed. Moreover, things like widgets that show last comments may show your comment. **3.** Your Codex example is wrong because of #1,: you *can* pass `'comment_approved' argument, but it will be just overridded.

Comment: do I revert the Codex edit?

Comment: Don't have time to see how it was before, if you just added `'comment_approved'` than yes, I think is better to revert, otherwise just delete that line @MayeenulIslam

Comment: That line was deleted. The [previous one](http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Function_Reference%2Fwp_new_comment&action=historysubmit&diff=151339&oldid=146484) was not an example at all.